# Why expressions a() and (****&a)() call the same function?

Tags: c++

There is this code:

```
void a() { }

int main(){
   a();
   (****&a)();
   return 0;
}
```

How does it happen that statement `(****&a)();` has the same effect as `a();`?

Comment: `(**********************************************************&a)();` works too.

Comment: Oh guys, really? With [12 minutes worth of difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625902/function-variable-instead-of-pointer-to-function)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's all because of *function-to-pointer conversion* (§4.3):

> An lvalue of function type `T` can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to `T`.” The result is a pointer to the function.

`&a` first gives you a pointer to `a`. Then you dereference it with `*` giving you the function itself. You then attempt to dereference that function, but since you can't, it undergoes function-to-pointer conversion to get the pointer again. You dereference that pointer with `*`, and so on.

In the end `(****&a)` denotes the function `a` and you call it, since you can apply `()` to a function without it undergoing function-to-pointer conversion.