# What is the difference between these two expressions

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void test(){
    int a = 100;
    cout << a << endl;
}
int main()
{
    void(*b)() = test;
    (*b)();         //expression one
    b();            //expression two
    return 0;
}
```

`test` is a pointer to function, isn't it? `(*b)()` is a correct form, because it is equivalent to function prototype. But Why is it correct to delete a symbol `*`? They all produced the right results.

Comment: OT: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: "`test` is a pointer to function"? No, but it will *decay* to a pointer to the function (i.e. `&test`). The variable `b` is a pointer to a (non-member) function.

Comment: `(**********b)();` would be correct too. It's a paradox inherited from C and is due to how  taking address of function and dereferencing a pointer works.

Comment: duplicates: [Why do function pointer definitions work with any number of ampersands '&' or asterisks '*'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6893285/995714), [Why expressions a() and (****&a)() call the same function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16626033/995714), [Is the asterisk optional when calling a function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23960436/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the asterisk optional when calling a function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23960436/is-the-asterisk-optional-when-calling-a-function-pointer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `test` is a pointer to function, isn't it?

No, it isn't. `test` is a function.

`b` is a pointer to function.

> But Why is it correct to delete a symbol *?

Because you can also invoke the function call operator on function pointers, and not just functions.

Furthermore, since a function can implicitly convert to a function pointer, this is also equivalent:

```
(********b)();
```

> What is the difference between these two expressions

One indirects through function pointer and invokes function call operator - which calls the pointed function.

The other invokes function call operator on a function pointer - which implicitly indirects through the pointer and calls the pointed function.

The former requires 3 more characters to write.

Answer (score 3):

`test` is the function, `b` is a pointer to function (which points to `test`); and [pointer to function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_functions) could be used in function-call expression directly.

> A pointer to function can be used as the left-hand operand of the function call operator, this invokes the pointed-to function:
>
> Dereferencing a function pointer yields the lvalue identifying the pointed-to function:
>
> ```
> int f();
> int (*p)() = f;  // pointer p is pointing to f
> int (&r)() = *p; // the lvalue that identifies f is bound to a reference
> r();             // function f invoked through lvalue reference
> (*p)();          // function f invoked through the function lvalue
> p();             // function f invoked directly through the pointer
> ```

Dereference on `b` like `*b` you'll get the pointed function `test`. As the effect, `(*b)();` and `b();` do the same thing, i.e. invoke `test`.

Answer (score 1):

> test is a pointer to function, isn't it?

`test` is not a pointer to a function. It is a function.

To make the difference between a function and a function pointer more visible consider the following code snippet.

```
using Fn = void();
using FnPtr = void ( * )( );

Fn test;
FnPtr test_ptr = test;

void test()
{
    int a = 100;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

In this code snippet there are introduced two aliases. The first alias `Fn` denotes the function type `void()`. The second alias `FnPtr` denotes the pointer type `void( * )()`.

So this record

```
Fn test;
```

declares the function `test` while this record

```
FnPtr test_ptr = test;
```

declares the function pointer `test_ptr` that is initialized by the address of the function test because the function designator `test` used as an initializer in this declaration is implicitly converted to a pointer to the function `test`. You could rewrite the declaration also the following way

```
FnPtr test_ptr = &test;
```

explicitly applying the address of operator.

These two function call expressions

```
(*b)();
b();
```

differ only in one aspect.

In the first call there is used a function lvalue. Neither implicit conversion from the lvalue to a function pointer is done.

In the second call there is used a function pointer.

From the C++ 14 Standard (5.2.2 Function call)

> 1. ...For a call to a non-member function or to a static member function,
>    the postfix expression shall be either an lvalue that refers to a
>    function (in which case the function-to-pointer standard conversion
>    (4.3) is suppressed on the postfix expression), or it shall have
>    pointer to function type

Pay attention to that you could call the function also the following way

```
( *test )();
```

In this case the function designator is implicitly converted to a pointer to the function and then after applying the operator * an lvalue to the function is obtained. S you may even write

```
( ******test )();
```

or

```
( *&*&*&test )();
```